# Devise hash password and old password style

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a User model with email(in this case a registry number) and a encrypted_password with 700 records, it was genereted by devise.

This looks like it

```
Number    encrypted_pasword
345       76576545672
```

I used this solution to convert this password in a string format to BCrypt valid has, but i'm getting this error

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2017-03-01 16:23:47 -0300
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"VnOD8783DV191j0CnruEdhDeF15SQjJEW6ilCeJxFRoZqaBuu6PtgRtfpyHeqE43KD6ra9c3e6BLitcltt2qng==", "user"=>{"email"=>"5262", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  User Load (4.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = '5262' ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 16ms (ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)



TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):

app/models/user.rb:13:in `digest'
app/models/user.rb:13:in `hexdigest'
app/models/user.rb:13:in `rescue in valid_password?'
app/models/user.rb:10:in `valid_password?'
```

User Model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  alias :devise_valid_password? :valid_password?

  def valid_password?(encrypted_password)
    begin
      super(encrypted_password)
    rescue BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash
      return false unless Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(password) == encrypted_password
      logger.info "User #{email} is using the old password hashing method, updating attribute."
      self.encrypted_password = encrypted_password
      true
    end
  end
end
```

Make this question is my last attempt to solve it.
Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**

I used this:

```
return false unless Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(:password.to_s) == encrypted_password
```

but I recieved this error and I was redirected to login page

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for ::1 at 2017-03-01 17:01:10 -0300
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+Gk/T1r1k1zHiLIXFCupiTxOudwcx1lLAQOiS6W7teiU54UUAvB6AvpmZ+LfXBpyiPbq9Z20IZ8bIyZdWqCx8g==", "user"=>{"email"=>"5262", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  User Load (4.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = '5262' ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1

Completed 401 Unauthorized in 40ms (ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)


Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+Gk/T1r1k1zHiLIXFCupiTxOudwcx1lLAQOiS6W7teiU54UUAvB6AvpmZ+LfXBpyiPbq9Z20IZ8bIyZdWqCx8g==", "user"=>{"email"=>"5262", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  Rendering C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/app/views/devise/shared/_links.html.erb (8.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.2.0/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (184.1ms)
  Rendered shared-templates/_header.html.erb (8.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1963ms (Views: 1627.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: could you post the code for your controller action `users#sign_in` or is that automatically handled by devise?

Comment: @eiko it was genereted by devise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 def valid_password?(input_password)
    begin
      super(input_password)
    rescue BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash
      return false unless Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(input_password) == encrypted_password
      logger.info "User #{email} is using the old password hashing method, updating attribute."
      self.password= input_password
      true
    end
  end
```

If you manually hash all your old passwords with bcrypt, you can do this instead:

```
def valid_password?(password)
  begin
    super(password)
  rescue BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash
    super(Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(password))
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, Eiko, thanks for helping.
it give an error

undefined local variable or method `params' for #<User:0xa42eab0>

Comment: But I don't know if I use "password" or "encrypted_password", because my model is set to encrypted_password

Comment: @VictorRodriguez i updated my answer with new code which will hopefully work.

Comment: I'm trying to use an each to get each password stored at db, hash it with BCrypt::Password.create and save it again. Is it a good ideia?

Comment: i think that is a good idea! if you manually convert your passwords, you can have a much simpler devise validation. i'll update my answer to reflect.